# Why is the Java 11 base Docker image so large? (openjdk:11-jre-slim)

Tags: java, docker, alpine-linux, java-11

Java 11 is announced to be the most recent LTS version. So, we're trying to start new services based on this Java version.

However, the base Docker image for Java 11 is much larger than the equivalent  for Java 8:

- [`openjdk:8-jre-alpine`](https://github.com/docker-library/openjdk/blob/master/8/jre/alpine/Dockerfile): 84 MB
- [`openjdk:11-jre-slim`](https://github.com/docker-library/openjdk/blob/master/11/jre/slim/Dockerfile): **283** MB

(I'm considering only the [***official OpenJDK***](https://hub.docker.com/_/openjdk/) and ***the most lightweight*** images for each Java version.)

Deeper digging uncovered the following "things":

- the [`openjdk:11-jre-slim`](https://github.com/docker-library/openjdk/blob/master/11/jre/slim/Dockerfile) image uses the base image `debian:sid-slim`. This brings 2 issues:

  - this is 60 MB larger than `alpine:3.8`
  - the [Debian `sid`](https://www.debian.org/releases/sid/) versions are unstable
- the `openjdk-11-jre-headless` package installed in the image is **3 times larger** than `openjdk8-jre` (inside running Docker container):

  - `openjdk:8-jre-alpine`:

    > ```
    > / # du -hs /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8-openjdk/jre/lib/
    > 57.5M   /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8-openjdk/jre/lib/
    > ```
  - `openjdk:11-jre-slim`:

    > ```
    > # du -sh /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/lib/
    > 179M    /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/lib/
    > ```

    Going deeper I discovered the "root" of this heaviness - it's the `modules` file of the JDK:

    > ```
    > # ls -lhG /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/lib/modules
    > 135M    /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/lib/modules
    > ```

So, now the questions which came:

- Why is `alpine` not used any more as a base image for Java 11 slim images?
- Why is the unstable *sid* version used for LTS Java images?
- Why is the slim/headless/JRE package for OpenJDK 11 so large compared to the similar OpenJDK 8 package?

  - What is this *modules* file which brings 135 MB in OpenJDK 11?

**UPD**: as a solutions for these challenges one could use this answer: [Java 11 application as docker image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53669151/java-11-application-as-docker-image/53669152#53669152)

Comment: Well for one new versions (JDK 9+) of Java are [modularized](https://www.oracle.com/corporate/features/understanding-java-9-modules.html), which explains why there are modules in 11 vs 8.

Comment: Related read possibly - [Benchmarking Debian vs Alpine as a Base Docker Image](https://nickjanetakis.com/blog/benchmarking-debian-vs-alpine-as-a-base-docker-image)

Comment: There is no JRE 11, so what you have, is a full JDK. You can create compact environments, even slimmer than JRE 8, but it requires an actual modular application, so that the dependencies are known.

Comment: Additionally to the above, not all those *modules* that you find as the reason of increase in size are actually required for your applications. But to find out which ones you shall proceed towards creating a modular application. You can find out more about [tag:jlink] (introduced in Java9) for that sake.

Comment: What could be a better time to get to read this online - https://twitter.com/LogicTheoryIO/status/1064503559071371265

Comment: @Holger
> There is no JRE 11, so what you have, is a full JDK.
Hm. This makes even more confusing, because there are both `11-jre-slim` and `11-jdk-slim`, but what is even more confusing: "src.zip" in that jdk image is a broken soft link (so, "src.zip" is not there!)

Comment: Dockerhub says 69mb. Or isn't that the final size? -> https://hub.docker.com/layers/openjdk/library/openjdk/11-jre-slim/images/sha256-145ffab4f761cb527609ebe3e5ceed61b298d33022b5bb5e432918fe9bfebf9d

Comment: the downloaded (pulled) image size is still 204 Mb (at least for current `openjdk:11-jre-slim` image). Not sure what size is published on Dockerhub. Maybe it's a size of the layer with JRE only.

Comment: AdoptOpenJDK has an alpine image for JRE 11 here: https://hub.docker.com/r/adoptopenjdk/openjdk11 . It's not an official image but maintained by AdoptOpenJDK

Answer (score 207, accepted):

> Why is `alpine` not used any more as a base image for Java 11 slim images?

That's because, sadly, there is no official stable OpenJDK 11 build for Alpine currently.

Alpine uses musl libc, as opposed to the standard glibc used by most Linuxes out there, which means that a JVM must be compatible with musl libc for supporting vanilla Alpine. The musl OpenJDK port is being developed under OpenJDK's [Portola](https://openjdk.java.net/projects/portola) project.

The current status is summarized on the [OpenJDK 11 page](https://jdk.java.net/11/):

> The Alpine Linux build previously available on this page was removed as of JDK 11 GA. It’s not production-ready because it hasn’t been tested thoroughly enough to be considered a GA build. Please use the early-access JDK 12 Alpine Linux build in its place.

The only stable OpenJDK versions for Alpine currently are 7 and 8, provided by the [IcedTea](https://icedtea.classpath.org/wiki/Main_Page) project.

However - if you're willing to consider other than the official OpenJDK, [Azul's Zulu](https://www.azul.com/downloads/zulu) OpenJDK offers a compelling alternative:

- It supports [Java 11 on Alpine musl](https://www.azul.com/downloads/zulu/zulu-download-alpine) (version 11.0.2 as of the time of writing);
- It is a certified OpenJDK build, verified using the OpenJDK TCK compliance suite;
- It is free, open source and docker ready ([Dockerhub](https://hub.docker.com/r/azul/zulu-openjdk-alpine)).

For support availability and roadmap, see [Azul support roadmap](https://www.azul.com/products/azul_support_roadmap).

**Update, 3/6/19:** As of yesterday, `openjdk11` is available in Alpine repositories! It could be grabbed on Alpine using:

```
apk --no-cache add openjdk11
```

The package is based on the `jdk11u` OpenJDK branch plus ported fixes from project Portola, introduced with the following [PR](https://github.com/alpinelinux/aports/pull/6469). Kudos and huge thanks to the Alpine team.

> Why is the unstable *sid* version used for LTS Java images?

That's a fair question / request. There's actually an open ticket for providing Java 11 on a stable Debian release:
https://github.com/docker-library/openjdk/issues/237

**Update, 26/12/18:** The issue has been resolved, and now the OpenJDK 11 slim image is based on `stretch-backports` OpenJDK 11 which was recently made available ([PR link](https://github.com/docker-library/openjdk/pull/259)).

> Why is the slim/headless/JRE package for OpenJDK 11 so large compared to the similar OpenJDK 8 package? What is this *modules* file which brings 135 MB in OpenJDK 11?

Java 9 introduced the module system, which is a new and improved approach for grouping packages and resources, compared to jar files. This article from Oracle gives a very detailed introduction to this feature:
https://www.oracle.com/corporate/features/understanding-java-9-modules.html

The `modules` file bundles all modules shipped with the JRE. The complete list of modules could be printed with `java --list-modules`. `modules` is indeed a very large file, and as commented, it contains all standard modules, and it is therefore quite bloated.

One thing to note however is that it replaces `rt.jar` and `tools.jar` which became deprecated, among other things, so when accounting for the size of `modules` when comparing to pre-9 OpenJDK builds, the sizes of `rt.jar` and `tools.jar` should be subtracted (they should take up some 80MB combined).

Answer (score 18):

If you are considering only Official Images and your target achievement is to use the smaller JRE image available, I would suggest you to look at the **official OpenJDK** image `openjdk:11-jre-slim-buster` which is just 69.2 MB.

Comment: https://hub.docker.com/layers/openjdk/library/openjdk/11.0.9-jre-slim-buster/

Comment: image size of openjdk:11-jre-slim-buster is 129.7MB !!!

Comment: @ЖасуланБердибеков I was referring to the compressed size, which is a good indicator to compare images sizes at runtime. Please see: https://hub.docker.com/layers/openjdk/library/openjdk/11.0.11-jre-slim-buster/images/sha256-1efc10742a26c56416e400611b1d7ba871dab6c478e8017ab0a226d87f26b78b?context=explore

Answer (score 13):

as for 07.2019 https://adoptopenjdk.net/ has official Alpine support for Java 11:

- https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-docker/blob/master/11/jdk/alpine/
- https://hub.docker.com/r/adoptopenjdk/openjdk11

However, modules (*jmods*, `jlink`) still shall be considered when one assembles minimal application.

**Note**: *slim* images don't contain some modules (like `java.sql`) - they are excluded explicitly (https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-docker/blob/21b8393b9c23f94d6921a56cce27b026537c6ca2/11/jdk/alpine/slim-java.sh#L233)

Comment: Thanks to your useful answer i got to understand what's excluded in the slim images. But one question i have is why does it exclude the `java.se` module aswell, isn't that needed??

Comment: The Eclipse Temurin images may be also interesting: https://hub.docker.com/_/eclipse-temurin

Answer (score 2):

https://hub.docker.com/_/openjdk?tab=tags&page=1&name=11.0.7-jre-slim

in docker openjdk repository, slim jre 11 image is less than 70mb

Comment: out of curiousity, do you know the difference between the two images there?

11.0.7-jre-slim-buster and 11.0.7-jre-slim

Comment: buster, jessie or stretch are the suite code names for releases of Debian and indicate which release the image is based on.