# OpenJDK Java 18 docker image

Tags: java, docker

We are upgrading our microservices in docker to use Java 18 and previously we used the base image openjdk:11.0.7-jre-slim. What is the corresponding image for Java 18?

There doesn't seem to be a openjdk:18-jre-slim?

Comment: "JRE is no longer a target of the OpenJDK project. "JDK 12+ has no official JRE build."
You could probably use either "eclipse-temurin:18-jre" or "eclipse-temurin:18-jre-alpine
" instead.

Comment: Please see the deprecation notice on [the Docker Hub `openjdk` image](https://hub.docker.com/_/openjdk), but all of the answers to the linked question about Java 17 also apply for Java 18.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use one of the [openjdk 18 liberica images](https://hub.docker.com/r/bellsoft/liberica-openjdk-alpine/tags?page=1&name=18)? They produce the smallest containers and they are TCK-verified for Java SE specifications. You could find more at their [dockerhub page](https://hub.docker.com/r/bellsoft/liberica-openjdk-alpine).

P.S. [One of my other answers and that question itself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53669151/java-11-application-as-lightweight-docker-image/58256837#58256837) could also come in handy. That was about JDK 11 but it has some details that are still relevant if you want it to be as lightweight as possible.