# adoptopenjdk alpine vs alpine-slim in AdoptOpenJDK maintained images

Tags: java, docker, java-11, adoptopenjdk

In the [AdoptOpenJDK maintained images docker hub repo](https://hub.docker.com/r/adoptopenjdk/openjdk11) i see that among others there are two builds for alpine namely ***alpine*** & ***alpine-slim***. I downloaded both & see a good 81 MB difference in the image size (see below) between both. I tried using the alpine-slim image to build & up my services and didn't see any issues.

I am now wondering what is the downside to using the ***alpine-slim*** image as opposed to the ***alpine*** one. Since i couldn't find much info in the docs on what is excluded in the slim image, i am wondering if anyone knows the details of the devil :-).

P.S: I also see that in the 'official' AdoptOpenJDK repo there are no alpine builds at all (i know they don't have alpine builds in there)...but with it being deprecated for the eclipse-temurin repo i am wondering what happens to the above repo that AdoptOpenJDK maintained till now..may be i should ask that as a separate question..

```
adoptopenjdk/openjdk11                                                                     jdk-11.0.11_9-alpine-slim   019bfca90bcf        3 weeks ago         260MB
adoptopenjdk/openjdk11                                                                     jdk-11.0.11_9-alpine        16b37a0cc6be        3 weeks ago         341MB
```

Comment: This answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/57144870/767949 should clarify your question

Comment: Thank you@null ! I had gone thru that post earlier but missed that detail in that answer! Thanks to you i got the info. Below is the excluded list,
`java.activation.jmod`
`java.corba.jmod`
`java.transaction.jmod`
`java.xml.ws.jmod`
`java.xml.ws.annotation.jmod`
`java.desktop.jmod`
`java.datatransfer.jmod`
`jdk.scripting.nashorn.jmod`
`jdk.scripting.nashorn.shell.jmod`
`jdk.jconsole.jmod`
`java.scripting.jmod`
`java.se.ee.jmod`
`java.se.jmod`

`java.sql.jmod`
`java.sql.rowset.jmod`

Comment: Sure Thank you @lmk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the list of [modules](https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-docker/blob/21b8393b9c23f94d6921a56cce27b026537c6ca2/11/jdk/alpine/slim-java_jmod_del.list) removed from slim distribution

```
java.activation.jmod
java.corba.jmod
java.transaction.jmod
java.xml.ws.jmod
java.xml.ws.annotation.jmod
java.desktop.jmod
java.datatransfer.jmod
jdk.scripting.nashorn.jmod
jdk.scripting.nashorn.shell.jmod
jdk.jconsole.jmod
java.scripting.jmod
java.se.ee.jmod
java.se.jmod
java.sql.jmod
java.sql.rowset.jmod
```

Kindly refer this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57144870/767949) for more details

Comment: When looking closely why is it excluding `java.se` module aswell, Isn't that core one needed?

Comment: OK got the answer [here.](https://cr.openjdk.java.net/~mr/jigsaw/ea/module-summary.html) Its just an aggregator module for the original Java SE unlike the `java.base` module which _**is**_ the core one.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the helpful pointer from @null & the useful link from @radistao, I got the below list looking at the code in [git](https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-docker/blob/21b8393b9c23f94d6921a56cce27b026537c6ca2/11/jdk/alpine/slim-java.sh#L233),

```
...
cat ${del_jmod_list} | grep -v "^#"
...

XXX@Ubuntu1_XX_XXX:~/XXX/server/etc/bin# cat /XXX/XXX/slim-java_jmod_del.list | grep -v "^#"
java.activation.jmod
java.corba.jmod
java.transaction.jmod
java.xml.ws.jmod
java.xml.ws.annotation.jmod
java.desktop.jmod
java.datatransfer.jmod
jdk.scripting.nashorn.jmod
jdk.scripting.nashorn.shell.jmod
jdk.jconsole.jmod
java.scripting.jmod
java.se.ee.jmod
java.se.jmod

java.sql.jmod
java.sql.rowset.jmod

XXX@Ubuntu1_XX_XXX:~/XXX/server/etc/bin#
```

Thanks